# Vimeo API returns 'File Error' after an upload with Plupload

Tags: html, file-upload, vimeo, plupload

I'm trying to create an upload form to send videos to Vimeo.

I've decided to use plUpload because I can easily manage when the upload is complete and handle the subsequent API calls that I need to complete the video upload.

The problem is that when the video has uploaded and I get the "Thanks for uploading!" response, calling **vimeo.videos.upload.complete** with the ticket and filename returns

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'VimeoAPIException' with message 'File error'
```

According to the API docs (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.upload.complete) it means that the file couldn't be uploaded - but as the upload method returns the "Thanks for uploading!" message I can't see what could be the problem.

plUpload succesfully sends the OPTIONs request; sends the video I'm testing (about 6MB) and gets a 200 OK response. Despite this, sending the video as a standard POST has no issues. Unfortunately because I need to continue with the API calls I can't use this method.

All I need to do is successfully complete the video upload and I'm sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an exceptional amount of time I've discovered that POST uploads use the *File Data Name* as **file_data** whereas Plupload defaults to **file**.

After using the option `file_data_name: 'file_data'` in Plupload everything has started to work. Clearly the header wasn't quite what Vimeo's API expected and so it didn't work.

Would have been nice if Vimeo returned something else besides *Thanks for uploading!* when it doesn't process anything.